# How can I open a menu smoothly with CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs

My code opens and closes the menu, but I want it to appear smoothly. In CSS I registered for class `menu` that will appear from left to right (`transform: translateX (-100%)` and will be visible for class `menu.active` but it does not work. What is my mistake?

JS React

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
export let Menu_Button = () => {

let [activeMenu, SetActiveMenu] = useState(false);

return (<div>

<div className='button_mobile' onClick={() => SetActiveMenu(!activeMenu)}>
        <span></span>
</div>

{activeMenu && <nav className= {activeMenu ? 'menu active' : 'menu'}>
 <div><a href='#'>BBBBBBBBBB</a></div>
 <div><a href='#'>BBBBBBBBBB</a></div>
 <div><a href='#'>BBBBBBBBBB</a></div>
 <div><a href='#'>BBBBBBBBBB</a></div>
 <div><a href='#'>BBBBBBBBBB</a></div>
</nav>}
</div>)
}
```

CSS

```
.menu{
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
width: 115px;
background-color: orange;
transform: translateX(-100%);
transition: all 0.3s;
}

.menu.active{
transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```css
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  /* top: 100%; */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 115px;
  background-color: orange;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.menu.active {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div className='button_mobile'>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  
  <nav class='menu active'>
    <div><a href='#'>BBBBBBBBBB</a></div>
    <div><a href='#'>BBBBBBBBBB</a></div>
    <div><a href='#'>BBBBBBBBBB</a></div>
    <div><a href='#'>BBBBBBBBBB</a></div>
    <div><a href='#'>BBBBBBBBBB</a></div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: For CSS questions like this it's best to show rendered HTML, not your JSX code. CSS doesn't care what your app code looks like. You can then build a functioning snippet using the editor.

Comment: Its also worth pointing out that your menu is either existing or NOT existing, so it won't have any smooth transition. You can either use React transition group, or you can always render the menu, but apply a different class based on whether its active or not then css transition: all 0.2s or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not a smooth transition is because your menu, if not active, will not even be rendered, so there is no transition.
Change

```
activeMenu && <nav className= {activeMenu ? 'menu active' : 'menu'}>
```

with

```
<nav className= {activeMenu ? 'menu active' : 'menu'}>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much

Comment: @Ronald do you mind bumping up my answer as correct solution so I can increase my rating